# QGIS multiple whitespace in attributes are removed after restart

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes

Concerning this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28660079/firefox-is-ignoring-more-than-one-whitespace-in-svg-text-and-showing-them-smalle

I have an issue with the **saving** of **Strings** with **multiple whitespace** in the **Attributes**. Let's say I want to save `S e a` it is fine, also after restart of QGIS.

But when I save `S   e   a`. After restart I get `S e a`. I really need the whitespaces at the specific count as you can see from the link above.

So I tried to save `"S   e   a"`. That is working somehow! But in the Geojson I now get `\"S   e   a\"`. Puh. That's bad...

So how can I safe multiple whitespaces that are not lost after QGIS restart?

Comment: Which QGIS version are you using and on what platform? I tested this on QGIS 2.2 and 2.6 for Windows 7 and the whitespaces remain after restart.

Comment: Windows 8.1 and QGIS 2.6.1.

Comment: Well I edit in the Attribute Table the Attribute. Click Save. When I reopen now, all is fine. But when I restart QGIS the multiple whitespaces are gone. What am I do wrong?

Comment: I cannot replicate your issue unfortunately. Have you tried creating a new string field, setting the field width to 99 and then testing the whitespaces?

Comment: Hey that's right. I created a new column and there it's working. But need that working on my old column =/ I will try some things out.

Comment: Glad that it's working, strange behavour. Why not just copy all values from the old column into the new one? You can use the **Field Calculator** to _update_ your new column with the expression: `"your_old_column"`

Comment: Puh I don't know man. But now it's also working on the old column. There must be something really damaged. Otherwhise I can't explain that behaviour. Cool also in the exported Geojson/Topojson the multiple whitespace are in there. Thank you very much. I think I would have gived up on this without you =)

Comment: Haha I didn't do anything :) But glad it's working now. Just to warn you, this post might get flagged as being "off-topic" as your issue couldn't be reproduced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Joseph, the issue was somewhere in the project. So if also having issues just create a new column and write in something and delete it.

Now retest on you column. Not reproduceable anyways!